# How to serve private image in html page with django?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a django website that serves media image with nginx. I implemented permissions adding 'internal' option in nginx configuration so I can download image with 'X-Accel-Redirect'. Now I can't see images in html pages.

This is the html page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head_title %}Image | {{ block.super}}{% endblock head_title%}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ object.title }} <small> {{ object.category }}</small></h1>
<p>{{ object.location }}</p>
<p>{{ object.timestamp }}, Updated {{ object.updated|timesince }} ago</p>
{% if object.image %}
<img src="{{object.image.url}}" alt="My image">
{% else %}
<p>No image</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the configuration of nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
      autoindex off;
      alias /project/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
      autoindex off;
      internal;
      alias /project/media/;
    }
}
```

The image is showed if there isn't the 'internal' option in the nginx configuration.

There is any method to show the image?

Comment: post the code. when you go on your site right click on the image what is the value of `src` ?

Comment: the src is src="/media/image.jpg"

Comment: this is not how its supposed to be. You need a proper image src link. Try to find out why its just "image.jpg". When you serve the file over a server there should be a link. You reference it wrong. The `<img src={{ yourVariable }}...` part is not right.

Comment: Django documentation says to do in this way. Any better method?

Comment: try `{% static object.image.url %}`.

Comment: It works but the src is src="/static/media/image.jpg". I want nginx loads the image with src="/media/image.jpg" because if media aren't in static folder it doesn't work.

Comment: in that case, you need to recheck your settings.py and urls.py.